# AngularJS : access scope object from parent to child

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, angular-ui-router

**Query :** Want to access the **`Main Controller`** scope object into **`ui-view`** **`states`**.

**Problem Statement :**

**Here,** I am creating one scope object(`$scope.myVar`) based on the response getting from the API that will be applicable across the application. hence, I wrote an API in `Main Controller` to create this scope object as it is a `parent` controller and all other states(`ui-view`) are `child`.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr4zK.png]
**Here,** I want to access that `$scope.myVar` in all the states in `ui-view`.

**Tried so far :** **HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  <div class="className">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Main Controller**

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.myVar = 'xyz'; // This variable i want to access into the state controller.
  }, function errorCallback(response) {        
  });
});
```

**State controller :**

```
app.controller('StateController', function($scope, $timeout) {

  console.log($scope.myVar); // undefined (Not working)

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.myVar); // xyz (working)
  }, 500);
});
```

I want to access **`$scope.myVar`** without using **`$timeout`** service. What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: You can use services if you want to share data between controllers.

Comment: Or you can use $broadcast

Comment: @NiteshRana As i already have the data in mainController and other controllers are child so need to use services in that case and `$broadcast` is used if we want to capture an event from parent to child but in my case i just want to pass the scope variable.

Comment: Okay, you should use dot(.) notation for your variable and should not put it on $scope. See this https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [angular $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Using promises and $q to handle asynchronous calls

```
var app = angular.module("MY_APP", []);
//Parent Controller
app.controller("MyCtrl1", [
    '$scope','$q','$timeout', function($scope,$q,$timeout) {

 $scope.async = function(name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  //Async call: Use your ajax call here instead of $timeout
  /*
  $http.get('/someUrl')
       .success(function(data) { 
          $scope.myVar = 'xyz';
          deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(msg, code) {
          deferred.reject(msg);
          $log.error(msg, code);
       });
  */
  $timeout(function() {
    deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');
     if (name) {
      deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
     } else {
      deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
     }
   }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}
}]);
//Child Controller
app.controller("MyCtrl2", [
    '$scope','$q', function($scope,$q) {
 // call parent async method
var promise = $scope.$parent.async('Sai');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
//check your variable here
/*
console.log($scope.$parent.myVar); 
*/
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function(update) {
  alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});

}]);
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/t1z4rh44/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$parent.myVar` to access data of `parentScope`

For your situation(async call), you can add `$scope.$watch` to watch the parent scope variable.

```
$scope.$watch("$parent.myVar", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.data = newValue;
)
```

---

Here you want to get data immediately when child state initializing, you can try with `resolve`.

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'hello',
  url: '/hello',
  templateUrl: '...',
  resolve: {
    testData: function($http) {
      // invoke your async call here again
    }
  }
})
```

here are some issues about `resolve` which may help.

- [how to resolve $http result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309661/angularjs-http-get-with-resolve)
- [Is it ok to $http request in resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562677/is-it-ok-to-do-the-http-get-request-on-ui-routers-resolve-in-angularjs)

Comment: Not working..getting `Unknown provider: $parentProvider <- $parent <- homeController` error. I already injected `$parent` in the controller.

Comment: @RohitJindal you don't have to inject `$parent`. use it directly.

Comment: I also checked with `$scope.$watch` it return me `undefined` if i am accessing the $scope.data outside of $scope.$watch.

Comment: @RohitJindal that is because you are fetching data with asynchorouse call, the data won't comeback immediately.

Comment: I agree with you but I want the solution for this issue.

Comment: @RohitJindal I give you another advice about ui-router's resolve. If this still is what you wish, I would say that's impossible...sorry

Comment: I have lot of states in my application and i want that variable in every state. then i have to add `resolve` property in each state.. ?

Comment: @RohitJindal Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144035/discussion-between-pengyy-and-rohit-jindal).

Comment: Correct way to share data would create a service.. also you could use `resolve` function.

Comment: @PankajParkar you can see above comments, OP seems don't want to use resolve. Also without resolve here, service won't help because OP want that data immedatiely when substate init.

Comment: @Pengyy we can directly inject service inside `ui-view`(inner named view)  controller, resolve isn't compulsory.. I think OP should use service which will be responsible for data sharing..

Comment: @PankajParkar I know what you means and thanks, mention that OP just want to access asynchronous result without call it again which sounds like making `asynchronous` to `synchronous`.

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for the comment. But still i have one confusion. As data is available in the mainController and it will not refresh if view changes their states. so we can directly use $scope in child from parent then what is the purpose of storing the data in service here ?

Comment: I know even data is present there in parent controller. asking it directly using `$parent` convention would make sense for me.. that way will introduce tight coupling inside your application(I never prefer it). Rather put inside a service(single resource responsible for data sharing). Have getter & setter inside a service to avail data in different places